# How exactly does Device Admin add a layer of security to uninstall app?

Tags: android, device-admin

So I have made my App Device admin to add a layer of protection. I am unable to uninstall the app when I try to Uninstall from HomeScreen as it tells you cannot uninstall the app as it is a device admin app. 
However, when I try to Uninstall the app from Settings - Uninstall, it uninstalls directly without asking me to remove the app as device admin.

Can I overcome this?
Can I ask the user to go to device admin and remove it post which user can uninstall ?

Can I block/grey out Uninstall until the app device admin?